# authorize.net payment gateway integration?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I have gone through https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/accept-sdk-android
and setup https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/accept-sample-android as per guidance, and also applied `CLIENT_KEY` and `API_LOGIN_ID` from my sandbox account.

I stuck into something here now, after `EncryptTransactionCallback` it comes to `onEncryptionFinished()` or `onErrorReceived()`. In my case it comes to   `onEncryptionFinished()`, it returns `getDataDescriptor()` and `getDataValue()`. There is no proper guidance what needs to be done after it.

Comment: Hi Please share me what you have done after getting token Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all in-app options, you send the encrypted payment data obtained in Step 1 to your server.

https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#mobile-in-app-transactions-create-an-accept-transaction

Comment: Thanks @rhldr for you response. I did all the four steps from https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/accept-sdk-android
and after 4th step, I get response.getDataDescriptor() and response.getDataValue()

Comment: @ParmendraSingh Exactly.  You've retrieved a token you must now submit a transaction as outlined in the In-App payments guide: http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/in-app.html

Comment: Thanks @rhldr this really helped me, I have a question do the test transactions on sandbox mode does not display on authorizenet sand box. 
Also I get following in response:
Successfully created transaction with Transaction ID: 0
 Transaction Response Code: 1
 Message Code: 1
 Auth Code: 000000
 Description: This transaction has been approved.

Comment: Hi Parmendra Singh can u help me how u send the json once u received token.. Thanks

Comment: AnyOne can help me ..Thanks